# Find/Replace in a specific Excel sheet using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help from you, good people. I have searched the net and can't find a solution to my problem. VB is not my forte, but due to a real backward system I am forced to use, VB seems to be the answer to cut my engineering time. I found a piece of code that works, but I need to expand on this.

I need this code to not search and replace from in every sheet, but just one specific sheet. Once I get this right, I will modify it to do more, a lot more. :)

So, how do I change this code to do that?

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook from a table
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

'Create variable to point to your table
  Set tbl = Worksheets("Table").ListObjects("Table1")

'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then

          sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
      Next sht
  Next x

End Sub
```

There is quite a bit more this code will end up doing, but it would not be fair to give the complete scope without monetary reward. Just this solution will suffice. :)

PS: Hope the format works out fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace() 
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim fndList As Integer 
Dim rplcList As Integer 
Dim tbl As ListObject 
Dim myArray As Variant

Set tbl = Worksheets("Table").ListObjects("Table1")
Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange 
Set sht = 'the sheet you want to run through
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
fndList = 1 rplcList = 2

For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2) 
      sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I do have another question if I may. I have written another script (If that is the right term to use?), but I need to execute it 215 times with different values each time. In the type of coding I do, I would use a Function Block (FB). What would be the right term to use for this in VB? I read up on functions in VB, but that seems to be the wrong "tool". Subs and loops seem to be closer to what I need. Before I go off on a tangent, please steer me in the right direction?

Comment: You would use a loop and call a function or a sub.  You can give methods parameter to start/use when you call them, only function can return a value. Thats like the only difference.